# Closed form for series of multiple sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I have a series that goes like that:

\begin{align}
(n=1)\qquad &\sum_{i=0}^x\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^i 1\bigg)\\
(n=2)\qquad  &\sum_{i=0}^x\bigg(\sum_{j=0}^i \bigg(1+\sum_{k=1}^j 2\bigg)\bigg)\\
(n=3)\qquad  &\sum_{i=0}^x\bigg(\sum_{j=0}^i \bigg(1+\sum_{k=1}^j \bigg(2+\sum_{l=2}^k 3\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)\\
(n=4)\qquad  &\sum_{i=0}^x\bigg(\sum_{j=0}^i \bigg(1+\sum_{k=1}^j \bigg(2+\sum_{l=2}^k \bigg(3+\sum_{m=3}^l 4\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)
\end{align}
and so on.

For each $n$, it is easy to write the sums in closed expressions:

\begin{align}
(n=1)\qquad &\frac{1}{2} (x+1)\,x \\
(n=2)\qquad &\frac{1}{6} (x+1)\,(x+2)\,(2x+3)\\
(n=3)\qquad &\frac{1}{24} (x+1)\,(x+2)\,(3x^2+5x+12)\\
(n=4)\qquad &\frac{1}{120} (x+1)\,(x+2)\,(4x^3+3x^2+33x+60)
\end{align}

What I would like to have is a closed or more compact expression that can give me the polynomials in $x$ for arbitrary $n$. I tried OEIS for the coefficients with little success, and also couldn't find if the polynomials (or parts thereof) are known.

Has someone seen such a construction for a sequence and has an idea how I could go about finding a closed or more compact expression?

Comment: The pattern of lower limits on the sums is a little strange. Should the $n=1$ case be $\sum_{i=0}^x\sum_{j=0}^i 1$ to match the other sums which all use $j=0$ on the second-to-outermost sum?

Comment: Sums like $\sum_{j=0}^i \bigg(1+\sum_{k=1}^j 2\bigg)$ are ambiguous - to find the $j = 0$ term of the outer sum we are setting $j = 0$ in the inner sum, but how is $\sum_{k=1}^0 2$ defined?

Comment: The $n=1$ is indeed different, also the polynomial doesn't have the $(x+1)(x+2)$ the others have. But that's the series I have. Maybe ignore the $n=1$ case, or maybe someone can spot a pattern...

Comment: The empty sums are defined to be zero, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^0 2=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we give a somewhat more compact expression. We look at the  case $n=3$ again and derive from it a representation for the general case.

> We have
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j_0=0}^x}&\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{j_1=0}^{j_0}\left(1+\sum_{j_2=1}^{j_1}\left(2+\sum_{j_3=2}^{j_2}3\right)\right)\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{j_0=0}^x\sum_{j_1=0}^{j_0}1+2\sum_{j_0=0}^x\sum_{j_1=0}^{j_0}\sum_{j_2=1}^{j_1}1+3\sum_{j_0=0}^x\sum_{j_1=0}^{j_0}\sum_{j_2=1}^{j_1}\sum_{j_3=2}^{j_2}1\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq  j_1\leq   j_0\leq  x}1+2\sum_{1\leq j_2\leq j_1\leq   j_0\leq  x}1+3\sum_{2\leq j_3\leq     j_2\leq j_1\leq   j_0\leq  x}1\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{x+2}{2}+2\binom{x+2}{3}+3\binom{x+2}{4}}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}(x+2)(x+1)+\frac{1}{3}(x+2)(x+1)x+\frac{1}{8}(x+2)(x+1)x(x-1)\\
> &=\frac{1}{24}(x+2)(x+1)(3x^2+5x-3)
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we multiply out and factor out the constants.
- In (2) we use  convenient representation to better see the index range.
- In (3) we note the number of summands given by the index range $2\leq j_3\leq j_2\leq  j_1\leq j_0\leq x$  is the number of ordered $4$-tupel $(j_0,j_1,j_2,j_3)$ between $2$ and $x$ with repetition. This number is given by the binomial coefficient
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{4+(x-1)-1}{4}=\binom{x+2}{4}
  \end{align*}

> In  general we have in the case $n=N$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j_0=0}^x}&\color{blue}{\left(\sum_{j_1=0}^{j_0}\left(1+\sum_{j_2=1}^{j_1}\left(2+\cdots+\sum_{j_N=N-1}^{j_{N-1}}N\right)\cdots\right)\right)}\\
> &=\sum_{0\leq  j_1\leq   j_0\leq  x}1+2\sum_{1\leq j_2\leq j_1\leq   j_0\leq  x}1+\cdots+N\sum_{N-1\leq j_N\leq\cdots\leq     j_2\leq j_1\leq   j_0\leq  x}1\\
> &=\binom{x+2}{2}+2\binom{x+2}{3}+\cdots+N\binom{x+2}{N+1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=1}^N k\,\binom{x+2}{k+1}}\\
> \end{align*}

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot! I just think you missed in the line above (4) that it should be $k-1$ before the binomial. Pulling out twice than leads to $$(x+1)(x+2)\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+1} {x \choose k-1}$$

Comment: @DNick: You're welcome.  We  have   $\binom{x+2}{k}=\frac{x+2}{k}\binom{x+1}{k-1}$, so the calculation seems to be correct.

Comment: I still think it should be $\sum_{k=1}^n k {x+2 \choose k+1}$ instead of your line above (4) though...

Comment: @DNick: Ah, now I see what you mean. Thanks, I will fix it.

Comment: @DNick: I  hope I could fix the problem. You might want to check it again.

Comment: Yep now it works perfectly. I think no further simplification is possible.

Comment: @DNick:  Fine, thanks for checking it again. I also don't think there's any further simplification possible.